Cut-off in PW and in SIESTA code
I have been recently reading more about the different implementations of PW codes (such as VASP, Quantum Espresso) and LCAO codes (such as Siesta) working in Periodic Boundary Conditions.
In particular, reading from previous questions on cut-off-related issues, I understood that the concept of cut-off should be the same in, let's say, VASP and SIESTA, with it being the real-space mesh density directly related through FFT to the plane wave kinetic energy cut off. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Consequently, a directly related question arises for me: in SIESTA, as in other codes, some calculations are performed in real-space while the majority are performed in reciprocal space, and thus the PBC used. However, SIESTA does not use plane waves but NAOs, consequently, how are calculations performed in reciprocal space if not with PW?
